# How to validate a database against an entity model?

Tags: c#, database, ado.net-entity-data-model

I allow users to specify the data source and connection details. When this is complete, I set the Entity connection string. How do I validate the database they have chosen against the entity model right away? I don't want to get further in the program to have it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the existence of a known table and/or use a version table to store the schema version.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more advanced. I guess I would have to code it myself. The problem with versioning is that most of the time I do not change the schema so I don't want to store the app version #. So I have to remember to manually update the database version # everytime the schema changes.